# Can't silently refresh security token, Azure B2C, Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor-webassembly, msal.js

I'm making a Blazor WASM app and followed these instructions to enable authentication.

[Secure and ASP.NET Core Blazor WASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

I added one line to the `Program.cs` file...

```
options.ProviderOptions.Cache.CacheLocation = "localStorage";
```

It seems to work - logging in, redirecting when not logged in, etc. But when the token expires after about an hour all my network calls through the injected `HttpClient` fail with `AccessTokenNotAvailableException`. This is super annoying. **Shouldn't the token get refreshed automatically with NO user interaction necessary? Or does refreshing a token always require user interaction?**

My workaround is to catch these exceptions and call Redirect like this. This introduces a bunch of UI the user doesn't expect and the redirect doesn't return the user to the place where the security problem occurred.

```
try {
    var result = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync...
    return result;
}
catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException e) {
    e.Redirect();
    return null;
}
```

My network calls happen through a Scoped service called `ServerStorage`. The HTTP client is initialized in Program.cs.

```
public ServerStorage(HttpClient httpClient) {
    this._httpClient = httpClient;
}

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("GroceriesWasmApp.ServerAPI"));
```

Comment: Do you still have this issue? With `ex.Redirect()` I wonder if some transactional API calls can be affected (where reloading the page may not yield desirable result or user experience).